# How to preserve the HEIC format when downloading Google Photos to desktop

Tags: icloud, photos.app, google

For reasons that escape me, I deleted about 15 jpegs from my iPhone XS (I only enabled iCloud Photo Library recently). I do maintain a copy of all photos taken on my iPhone to Google Photos, and so I thought I could simply download those photos to my desktop and then import them into Photos to replace those I've lost. But when I do so, Google Photos *inexplicably* converts some of the HEIC files to JPEGs! (i.e. one sees the jpegs in the downloaded zipped file, so the conversion isn't happening on my Mac). This occurs with any browser (Safari, Firefox, Brave) that I use.

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I can do to prevent it, or else recommend a workaround?

Comment: You did look into photos, recently deleted?